# "Nineteenth hundred and sive" instead of "Nineteenth hundred and seven"

Tags: meaning, translation, mistranslation

From [the copyright page of Retana's *Vida y escritos del Rizal* (1907)](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina:Vida_y_escritos_del_Dr._Jos%C3%A9_Rizal,_por_Wenceslao_Retana.pdf/8)

> Se acabó de imprimir el 30 de Junio de 1907. — Inscripto en la oficina de la Propiedad literaria de los Estados Unidos, donde fué presentado el 22 de Julio siguente, de conformidad con la Ley al efecto de 3 de Marzo de 1905, á solicitud de W. E. Retana.
>
> *Published June 30, nineteenth hundred and sive. — Privilege of copyright in the United States reserved under the Act approved March 3, 1905 by*
>
> (signature of Retana)

Note that the phrase "30 de Junio de 1907" is translated to "June 30, nineteenth hundred and sive". Is "sive" here an old-timey way of saying "seven", or is this just a simple mistranslation?

Comment: I've never heard of 'sive' as a word, also I've never seen a century referred to as "nineteenth hundred". Even if someone did that it would be incorrect as the dates starting 19_ (except for 1900 itself) are in the _twentieth_ century not the nineteeth. I think that it's either a very poor translation or a joke.

Comment: In your position, I would look for a different edition and check whether the error still exists.

Comment: The error does not exist in a different copy (not necessarily different _edition_) of the book. I'll go post my answer immediately. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It's an error.

From [Mari-Lou A's suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/575393/nineteenth-hundred-and-sive-instead-of-nineteenth-hundred-and-seven/575398#comment1434571_575393) I went ahead and looked at a different "edition" of the book.

The typo exists in the [University of California copy (IA: vidayescritosde00unamgoog)](https://archive.org/details/vidayescritosde00unamgoog/page/n8/mode/2up) but not in the [Harvard College copy (IA: vidayescritosde00retagoog)](https://archive.org/details/vidayescritosde00retagoog/page/n11/mode/2up). In addition, "nineteenth hundred" is now referred to as "nineteen hundred" here (from [BoldBen's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/575393/nineteenth-hundred-and-sive-instead-of-nineteenth-hundred-and-seven/575398#comment1434570_575393)):

[image: Image of the copyright page with the correct date]

I can't deduce if they are different *printings*, *copies*, or *editions*, since from a quick glance the text is the same, but that already goes beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: This would appear to be your research for the question, not the answer to the question. The question is "I've found *sive* and I've found *seven.* Has *sive* ever meant *seven*?" as it could be that an obscure word was altered to a more common word in subsequent printings. If that were the case, it would not necessarily be an error.

Comment: "June 3ord"? Another error? I wonder if someone misread that "five" as as "sive" based on the way s used to be written similar to f in certain places in a word?

Comment: @AndrewLeach you're not wrong, but for the sake of this question, this is a good enough answer. From the commenters of this question, *sive* appears to not be a word, that has ever existed, that means "seven", but it will be difficult to prove that it has never existed to mean "seven". The OED is a "fairly good" record of words that have ever existed.

Comment: My point is that you cannot assume it's an error.

Answer (score 4):

*Sive* is [included in the OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180545) (link may be paywalled) but in the context given its use is nonsense.

> **sive,** *n.*
>
> = **chive** *n.<sup>1</sup>* 1.
>
> > 1707   J. Mortimer *Whole Art Husbandry* (1721) II. 171   Sives are a diminutive kind of Leek.

OED is a historical dictionary and *sive* has never meant *seven.*